# What exactly happens when a MySQL query throws a MySqlException in VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My problem is, I have the following code for inserting an entry into a table in a MySQL database:

```
Dim entryInserted As Boolean = True
Try
    connection.Open()
    If insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
        entryInserted = False
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, ErrorOccurred & ": Could 
            not insert into database.")
    End If
Catch ex As MySqlException
    entryInserted = False
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, ErrorOccurred & ": An 
    error occurred while trying to insert to the database.")
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

The insertCommand is an INSERT INTO statement. This insert will usually need to be done multiple consecutive times as it inserts data from a file and then deletes that data from the file, so I was trying to make sure that if the connection of the program is lost and a MySqlException is thrown, that the data will not be deleted from the file to avoid losing this data and save it for whenever a connection is available. For this reason, I've been disabling the Local Area Connection while the process of inserting data went on to ensure this is working correctly. However, I was under the assumption that if a MySqlException is thrown, then this means that the data was not inserted into the table (hence why I turn entryInserted to false in this case). But, when I look at the data of the last entry inserted in the table and the data of the query during which the connection was disabled and which caused the MySqlException, I found that they are the same? Meaning that even though a MySqlException was thrown while executing this query in the Try block, the data was inserted regardless? So I want to know, what happens when a MySqlException is thrown, since apparently it is not necessarily a guarantee that the query was not successful? How can I make sure that a query was unsuccessful in a situation like this? The reason I want to know this is because I want to avoid losing data in the case of a connection loss but I also don't want to save data which has already been inserted, leading to duplicate information in the table.

Comment: Can you wrap in a Transaction and them Rollback in the Catch?

Comment: @Mary, you wouldn't be able to explicitly rollback a transaction if the connection is lost. That said, I would think that the server would at least be able to implicitly rollback a transaction that wasn't explicitly committed.

Comment: As for the issue, there are presumably multiple steps involved in executing the command. The record would have to be inserted before the return value can be determined and if an issue occurred between those two then you'd see the record but the method would still not complete properly. The exception presumably has one or more properties that tell you what actually happened. Have you checked that information?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm not exactly sure what you mean by properties. Here's what the exceptions say, there's two, one when the connection is disabled and one when the program tries to execute the command. The first one says: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. The second exception is a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

Comment: If you don't know what properties are then you don't know the absolute basics of .NET programming, so you should spend some time with a beginner tutorial.